# Looping to find matching values in two dictionaries

Tags: python, json, python-2.7, dictionary

I have two different files which consist of dictionaries. I am trying to loop through the key ('name') only , value in the first file of dictionaries and match them with the second file. I seem to be getting the wrong output as it loops through both keys 'name' and 'size'. I have looked at a few ways of doing this but i don't want to be able to convert my dictionary to a set. I want to be able to print out either "match" or "no match". I have done the following so far :

```
def compare_files():

with open('new.json', 'r') as current_data_file, open('old.json','r') as pre_data_file:

    for current_data, previous_data in zip(current_data_file, pre_data_file):

        data_current = json.loads(current_data)
        data_previous = json.loads(previous_data)



        for key, value in data_current.items():
            if value not in data_previous:
                print "No Match"
            else:
                print "Match"
```

These are my two json files that i am loading :

old.json

```
{"name": "d.json", "size": 1000}
{"name": "c.json", "size": 1000}
{"name": "b.json", "size": 1000}
```

new.json

```
{"name": "a.json", "size": 1000}
{"name": "b.json", "size": 1000}
{"name": "c.json", "size": 1000}
```

data_current is :

```
{u'size': 1000, u'name': u'a.json'}
{u'size': 1000, u'name': u'b.json'}
{u'size': 1000, u'name': u'c.json'}
```

data_previous is :

```
{u'size': 1000, u'name': u'd.json'}
{u'size': 1000, u'name': u'c.json'}
{u'size': 1000, u'name': u'b.json'}
```

Output :

```
No Match
No Match
No Match
No Match
No Match
No Match
```

My expected output is :

```
No Match
Match
Match
```

b.json and c.json exists in both , but a.json and d.json does not.

Comment: Did you try `if value not in data_previous.values():`? This way you just check in the values and not both keys and values

Comment: I am trying to just check the values for key 'name' only and not 'size' ? @Bazingaa

Comment: You have no check on key if you just want to check for key `'name'`. Also, `if value not in data_previous` is not checking the value of `data_previous` but rather it is comparing value in `data_current ` with key in `data_previous`

Comment: @sparkdev I'm unsure what your expected output is? I'm assuming its not in the question.

Comment: I have updated my question @RoadRunner

Comment: can you also dump the output of `data_current` and `data_previous`

Comment: I have dump the output for you @mad_

Comment: the type of `data_current` is confusing as it is not a list nor a dict nor a list of dicts

Comment: You somehow need to put `data_previous = json.loads(previous_data)` outside the for loop to iterate over the values every time for each entry of `current_data`

Answer (score 2):

To save yourself from troubles you can directly read the data using pandas(a third party library) and can do the analysis very easily

```
import pandas as pd

df=pd.DataFrame('new.json')
df2=pd.DataFrame('old.json')

df.name.isin(df2.name).replace({False:'No Match',True:'Match'}).tolist()
```

**Output**

```
['No Match', 'Match', 'Match']
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple problems in your code.

1. When you do `if value not in data_previous:` you actually check if `value` is in **keys** of `data_previous`, not in its values.
2. When you do `zip(current_data_file, pre_data_file)`, you actually looking at *corresponding* pairs of the two dictionaries. Here, you have 3 dictionaries with 2 keys in each, that's why you have 6 output lines instead of 3. In other words, you are looking up the data in pairs, not comparing every dictionary in a data to all the others in the other data.

Here's a sample code:

```
def compare_files():
    with open('new.json', 'r') as current_data_file, open('old.json','r') as pre_data_file:
        # load both data 
        data_currents = [json.loads(line) for line in current_data_file]
        data_previous = [json.loads(line) for line in pre_data_file]

        # store the previous names for convenient lookup
        pre_names = set([data["name"] for data in data_previous])

        # loop through all current data for matching names
        for data in data_currents:
            print("Match" if data["name"] in pre_names else "No Match")
```

Comment: How can i loop through two different files instead of using zip. Would i have a nested for loop @QuangHoang

Comment: You would need to do nested for of some sort, something like in @Karl's answer.

Answer (score 0):

You for each "current" item you have to compare with all "previous" items, not just with the one in the same position (which is what "zip" would help you achieve)

```
data_current = [{"name": "d.json", "size": 1000},
                {"name": "c.json", "size": 1000},
                {"name": "b.json", "size": 1000}]

data_previous = [{"name": "a.json", "size": 1000},
                 {"name": "b.json", "size": 1000},
                 {"name": "c.json", "size": 1000}]

for current in data_current:
    result = "No Match"
    for previous in data_previous:
        if current["name"] == previous["name"]:
            result = "Match"
    print(result)
```

EDIT: If you want to check the items of current against previous and also previous against current, you could do the following (I've added some text to the prints clarify what is happening)

```
checks_to_run = [
    {
        "from": data_current,
        "from_name": "current", #Added for transparency
        "against": data_previous,
        "against_name": "previous", #Added for transparency
    },
    {
        "from": data_previous,
        "from_name": "previous", #Added for transparency
        "against": data_current,
        "against_name": "current", #Added for transparency
    }
]

for check_to_run in checks_to_run:
    for check_from in check_to_run["from"]:
        result = "No Match"
        for check_against in check_to_run["against"]:
            if check_from["name"] == check_against["name"]:
                result = "Match"
        print("result for item {} from {} compared to items in {}: {}".format(check_from["name"],
                                                                              check_to_run["from_name"],
                                                                              check_to_run["against_name"],
                                                                              result))
```

Comment: I see that in your code in prints "No Match" for values in data_current. How can I also print out "No Match" for values in data_previous. It will have to print out values that do not exists in data_current and data_previous @Karl

Comment: In that case just do it twice. Check each item of current against the full list of previous. Then check each items of previous against the full list of current. I'll update my answer with a small example